# Dilemma with overloaded method selection

Tags: java

```
public void testFunc(Object o) {
     System.out.println("testFunc-Object");
}

public void testFunc(String s) {
     System.out.println("testFunc-String");
}
```

Both of these methods are in test class. If I invoke the following method from main method of test class, which method will be invoked?

```
Test t = new Test();
t.testFunc(null);
```

In this particular scenario, `testFunc(String)` is called, but why?
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you asking *why* the answer is what it is? Which function is selected can be seen by compiling and running the code.

Comment: @sibbo i obviously tried the code, and it invoked function with argument String, but the question is why ??

Comment: @dlev i tried the code, and it invoked function with argument String, but why?

Comment: It's not actually obvious that you tried it because you didn't say what happened.  But see Sahil's answer below.

Comment: @andronikus u r right, i should have mentioned that, gonna edit the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`testFunc(String s)` gets invoked because the runtime will choose the variant of `testFunc` with the most specific argument. `testFunc(String s)` is more specific than `testFunc(Object o)` because `String` is a subtype of `Object`.

Peruse [section 15.12.2.5 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5) for explicit details.

Comment: isn't null equally close to both String and Object ??

Comment: I think what "most specific" means here is that String is a subclass of Object, so Java prefers an applicable subclass over its superclass.  The really interesting question is what would happen if you had functions that took a String and an Integer.

Comment: @andronikus "ambiguous function" compile time error comes, if u have 2 functions in same scenario, but with Integer and String as arguments

Comment: @andronikus so it seems that this particular scenario is possible only when arguments are from the same hierarchy

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I think I've actually gotten that.  Out of curiosity, does it complain about the functions or the `testFunc(null)` line?

Comment: @andronikus when arguments are Integer and String, it complains at the line testFunc(null)

Comment: @andronikus No, there are no compiler warnings in this case. If the dispatch is ambigious, the compiler will flat out throw an error.

Comment: Ah, fun with static typing.  Note that Python, which I love dearly, won't complain about a problem less serious than a syntax error until it actually runs the code, which is just egregiously bad.

Comment: I guess that's the dynamic language trade off. In return you get meta programming power, the ability to treat code as data and succinct syntax :)